# ON the third week

Tags: prepositions

I find the following example sentence here at [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/each)

"Your salary will be paid on the third week of each calendar month."

I often see IN used before WEEK. Can you please tell me what ON means here? Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: You overstate the case. Using ***on*** instead of ***in*** in such contexts is [less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+second+week%2Cin+the+second+week&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20second%20week%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20second%20week%3B%2Cc0), but it's ott todescribe the usage as an "error". Especially when *paid **on the** Nth week* is being used in a "repeating" context where it very specifically means *paid **every** Nth week*.

Comment: What have you found by looking up **on** in a dictionary?

Comment: @FeliniusRex What does the ON here mean?